# Creating two separated sections in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to create two separated sections in wordpress. Every section with it's own URLs. For example:

For section 1:

```
http://domain/section-1/page1/
http://domain/section-1/page2/
....
http://domain/section-1/pageX/
```

For section 2:

```
http://domain/section-2/page1/
http://domain/section-2/page2/
....
http://domain/section-2/pageX/
```

Templates would be differents and pages too.

How this can be treated with wordpress ?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for WordPress multi-site mode:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network